# Every two adjacent elements in this list forms an ordered pair in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have questions about this one
Every two adjacent elements in this list forms an ordered pair

Input: 1 4 2 4 3 8

Output: RELATION: { (1,4), (2,4), (3,8) }

I use Scanner to read the line and after that I use :

```
List<String> rel = Arrays.asList(relation.split(" "));
String rel1 = String.join(", ", rel);
System.out.println("RELATION: "+"{ "+rel1+" }");
```

but the output just gave me: RELATION: { 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 8 } not pair them in 2 like the output I wanted. Could someone help me with this please?

I also used this code but it gives me wrong pairs

```
(1,4
4,2
2,4):
for (int i=0;i<rel.size()/2;i++){
System.out.println(rel.get(i)+","+rel.get(i+1));}
```

Comment: What if the list has an odd number of elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i=0;i<rel.size()/2;i++){
System.out.println(rel.get(i)+","+rel.get(i+1));}
```

`i` only goes up by one each time, so of course it will emit `(1, 4)`, `(4, 2)`, ...

You probably want something like

```
for (int i=0;i<rel.size();i += 2)
```

which increases `i` by two every time.  Alternately, you could write `rel.get(2 * i)` and `rel.get(2 * i + 1)`, if you thought that was better.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work according to your requirement -

```
String relation = "1 4 2 4 3 8";
List<String> rel = Arrays.asList(relation.split(" "));
for (int i=0;i<rel.size();i+=2){
   System.out.println(rel.get(i)+","+rel.get(i+1));
}
```

Comment: Aw Thank you! May I ask how can I print out like the output example which is RELATION: { (1,4), (2,4), (3,8) }
, please?

Comment: `String ans = "RELATION: {";
String relation = "1 4 2 4 3 8";
List<String> rel = Arrays.asList(relation.split(" "));
for (int i=0;i<rel.size();i+=2){
     ans += "(" + rel.get(i)+","+rel.get(i+1) + ")";
}
ans += "}";
System.out.println(ans);`

Comment: Can you teach me more clearly about this part please? Because when I put it in, it didnt work 

Comment: You can take one String variable before starting the for loop and initialise it with `String ans = "RELATION : {"` . Then you can append all the relations to your string variable in the for loop. And after the for loop ends, then you can append ending bracket `}` to your string variable and print it.

Comment: oh it works perfectly, thank you so much!, I also have a question to convert the string to the set of relation so I can check them if they are onto, one to one or bijection. Do you have any idea about it? Thank you so much Aman Mehta

Comment: You can ask your question in detail. Also if this solution worked for you, then don't forget to accept the answer and upvote 